# Windows 8.1 doesn't boot unless I boot from installation USB

Tags: windows, usb, installation, setup

I can successfully install Windows 8.1 on a Samsung Series 5 Ultra, but when I try to boot the system it only shows a menu with the main HDD as an option. I select it and nothing happens. The only way to boot into Windows is through the installation USB by selecting "Repair..." and then "Continue to Windows 8.1" (I'm translating from Spanish, I don't know how it's written in English).

Also, while the Windows installation detects there is a Windows already installed on the system, "BootRec.exe /ScanOS" doesn't.

Any ideas on what could be happening? I would appreciate any input.

Extra info: the notebook has one HDD and one SSD. The SSD es completely inaccessible during boot, for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds to me like there was a windows installed on the HDD before and the computer boots from this mbr which is pointing to the old installation of the hdd, but instead it should boot from the ssd.

Comment: I think something in the notebook's general configuration messed up with Windows installation: I finally managed to install Windows by moving the HDD to another computer where it was the only drive and it booted normally when moved back to the Samsung computer.